# Terragrunt errors saying terraform not in %PATH% even though it is

Tags: heroku, terraform, terragrunt

I am trying to use Terragrunt for the first time. I have directory with terraform.tfvars. When I run "terragrunt get" just to get ball rolling, I get:

> **[terragrunt] 2017/08/08 11:08:14 exec: "terraform": executable file not found in %PATH%**

This is despite that fact I have terraform in my path. What could be wrong?

I am using Gitbash as my shell on Windows 7 machine. I use terraform literally several times a day from gitbash.

```
 $ which terragrunt
/c/WINDOWS/system32/terragrunt

 $ which terragrunt
/c/WINDOWS/system32/terragrunt

~/GITS/terra-heroku/us/dev (master)
$ which terraform
/c/WINDOWS/system32/terraform

~/GITS/terra-heroku/us/dev (master)
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.9.4

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.10.0. You can update by downloading from www.terraform.io

~/GITS/terra-heroku/us/dev (master)
$ terragrunt --version
terragrunt version v0.12.25

 #cat terraform.tfvars
terragrunt = {
  terraform {
    source = "git::git@github.com:westfieldcorp/tf-m-heroku-spsr-stack.git"
  }

include = {
    path = "${find_in_parent_folders()}"
  }
}

app_name = "foobar-service"   

$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/mr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/mrashid/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files (x86)/WebEx/Productivity Tools:/c/Program Files/Lenovo/Touch Fingerprint Software:/c/Program Files (x86)/Sennheiser/SoftphoneSDK:/c/opscode/chefdk/bin:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLI:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/idmu/common:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Users/mrashid/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts:/c/Users/mrashid/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36:/c/Ruby22/bin:/c/Users/mr/.babun:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Users/mrashid/.babun/cygwin/bin:/c/pstools:/c/Program Files/Heroku/bin:/c/users/mrashid/appdata/Local/programs/python/python36:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when "terraform init" command has not been run. Once, that was done, terragrunt worked.

Comment: That's odd - `terragrunt` runs auto-init by default, so running an `get` should've run `init`.

Comment: Thanks, seemed obvious once I read this

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of others who are also facing similar issue with Terragrunt i.e. `"terraform": executable file not found in $PATH`. Please check if you have installed terraform executable properly or not. To verify that follow:

1. `which terraform`

sample output -> `/bin/terraform`

2. `echo $PATH`

sample outut -> `/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Here we can observe that the **/bin** path is missing. To add that execute below command

3. `echo "PATH=$PATH:/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`
4. `source ~/.bashrc`
5. `terragrunt init` OR `terragrunt run-all init`

This should work fine now.